# Javascript - Onclick show inline - hide if clicked somewhere else

Tags: javascript, onclick, hide, inline

I want a text to be shown, when a button is clicked, and hidden again when you click somewhere else.
I added an onclick function, that changes the display from none to inline and vice versa.
What do I have to change, to make the text disapear again, without having to click the button again?

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: 
Solved it with the "onBlur" event, setting it to hide again.

Comment: You need to intercept the "onClick somewhere else" event. Where does that somewhere else's click go? Add a listener to that.

Comment: It depends what else you want to click on for the text to disapear? What code do you have already? a jsFiddle of your html and javascript would be useful?

Answer (score 0):

Remove your current click handler. Then instead add one to the document and check `e.target` if it's your button or not.

```
var toggle = document.getElementById('toggle');

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    toggle.style.display = e.target.id === 'btn' ? 'block' : 'none';
}, false);
```

*Handling for old browsers not included*

http://jsbin.com/ijawig/1

Answer (score 0):

Put this code between `<script></script> tags

> document.onclick = onclickFunc;
>   function onclickFunc(e) {
>   if (!e) var e = window.event
>          var id = e.srcElement.id;
>          if(id != 'btnId') {
>               **/*write your code to hide the panel*/**
>       }
>   }